# map respective values in arrayed r data frame

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe

is there any way to get the respective values from columns of an arrayed data frame in which the order of reference is described in one.

Example data

```
data.frame(ref="ENSG00000272602.1;ENSG00000272602.4;ENSG00000272602.2" , b="0;1;0", c="1;3;0",  d="0;1;7", e="0;3.2;2")

                                                 ref    b     c      d   e 
ENSG00000272602.1;ENSG00000272602.4;ENSG00000272602.2 0;1;0 1;3;0 0;1;7  0;3.2;2
```

desired output

```
                ref b c d e
1 ENSG00000272602.4 1 3 1 3.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separate_rows()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

target <- "ENSG00000272602.4"
df %>% 
  separate_rows(everything(), sep =  ";") %>%
  filter(ref == target)

                ref b c d   e
1 ENSG00000272602.4 1 3 1 3.2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can split at the `;` with `cSplit` into 'long' format and use `filter_at` to get the rows with any non-zero values

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
cSplit(d1, names(d1), ";", "long") %>%
         filter_at(-1,  any_vars(. > 0))
#                ref b c d   e
#1 ENSG00000272602.4 1 3 1 3.2
```

---

Or using `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyr)
d1 %>%
     separate_rows(everything(), sep= ";") %>% 
     filter_at(-1,  any_vars(. > 0))
#               ref b c d   e
#1 ENSG00000272602.4 1 3 1 3.2
```

#### data

```
d1 <- data.frame(ref="ENSG00000272602.1;ENSG00000272602.4;ENSG00000272602.2" , b="0;1;0", c="1;3;0",  d="0;1;7", e="0;3.2;2")
```

Comment: @akrun awesome. to clarify your answer, the output gives this ```                 ref b #c d   e
#1 ENSG00000272602.1 0 1 0 0.0
#2 ENSG00000272602.4 1 3 1 3.2
#3 ENSG00000272602.2 0 0 7 2.0  ```

Comment: @shams Not clear from the comments as I can't reproduce your output with the data I have in my post.

Comment: I meant to say the out put is each ref is split it respective raw with its value. Here we get three raws.. Dont know how to format that output to the comment. @andrew_reece has the exact answer to the question though your one also work but need one additional step to subset the raw. Hope this made it clear. By the way I need both the answers!. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, we can split the string on `";"`, create new rows and then filter row based on `target`.

```
library(data.table)
target <- "ENSG00000272602.4"

setDT(df)
df[,lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ";", fixed=TRUE)))][ref == target]

#                 ref b c d   e
#1: ENSG00000272602.4 1 3 1 3.2
```